# Highcharts add more than one legend for a series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Is there a way to add more than one legend to highchart series.

I need that to show hide data points on the basis of data in the series.

Don't want to add more than one series due to some other dependencies in the code.

Comment: Please share what have you tried till now

Comment: Highcharts does not offer that out of the box. A legend is attached to a series unless you use a pie type. You can still build your own custom legend but it requires some coding.

Comment: Thanks @morganfree can show any reference example of adding custom legend Please?

Comment: Example with an html legend http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/49pre/ You can also build a legend with Highcharts Renderer (it will be an svg legend) http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer

Comment: Example is showing number of data series, I want that for a single data series only.
Anyways thanks for your help as Highcharts does not offer that.